# evaluating a string in a condition

Tags: c++, qt

How to work with a string to evaluate numbers coming into a condition?

```
string = "(t>=2 && t<5) || (t<1)";

int c = 0;
for(int t = 0; t < 10; t++){
    if(  {string} )
        c++;
}
```

Comment: C++ is not an interpreted language, you know that correct?

Comment: You can send that string to gpu in an opencl  kernel code(C99) but I dont know for host code.  Connot do as automated C++(you need to look inside of string, you need a compiler code that compiles).

Comment: Essentially, you can't do this unless you write a function to take in a string and parameters and parse the string using the parameters, returning the 'truth value' of that string.

Comment: Try Lisp.  You might have better luck.

Comment: @qaphla, that is what I am trying to avoid... as this is just a simple case.

Comment: @jdl you cannot avoid it.

Comment: You'll probably have to create a function that parses your string, evaluates it, and returns a bool.  You might want to look up implementations of PEMDAS-Compliant calculators in C++, the concept would be the same, but using binary operators instead of arithmetic ones (and a true/false condition instead of total, of course).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse text for a DSL at compile time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17783393/how-to-parse-text-for-a-dsl-at-compile-time)

Comment: do you know your string at compile time? remove the quotes, convert to lambda function with capture by reference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's about Qt I would write something like

```
QScriptEngine e;
e.globalObject().setProperty("t", 123);

bool result = e.evaluate("(t>=2 && t<5) || (t<1)").toBool();
```

Comment: trying to use this... I get errors: I #include <QtScript/QScriptEngine>. But even with just the line "QScriptEngine e;" I get "undefined reference to 'QScriptEngine::QScriptEngine()'... ??

Comment: needed:   QT += script  ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128157/undefined-reference-to-qscriptengineqscriptengine

Answer (score 4):

if you want an embedded scripting language (you havent given us the broader context of what you are trying to do) then there are several you can try. Lua is very c friendly (I have used it and it was fine) google's V8 javascript engine is supposed to be very good in c++ (I have not tried it). You can  embed python too but many people don't like its syntax

Comment: if that means you are resource constrained then lua is the way to go.

Answer (score -2):

You cannot do that in C++ as far as I know.

Comment: You can, but it's not trivial. (You have to parse the string first, and then evaluate the resulting expression)

Comment: @Borgleader: And do variable substitution.

Comment: You can't? [This answer says otherwise](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17807607/1381108).

Comment: Better tell all the compiler and parser devs to go home then.