# "undefined reference to 'QScriptEngine::QScriptEngine()"

Tags: c++, qt

Given this code, I get:  "undefined reference to 'QScriptEngine::QScriptEngine()"

```
#include <QtScript/QScriptEngine>

...

QScriptEngine e;

/* Commented out to understand the instantiation error first
e.globalObject().setProperty("t", 123);

bool result = e.evaluate("(t>=2 && t<5) || (t<1)").toBool(); 
*/
```

Comment: Add `QT += script` to your project file.

Comment: Just to be sure you know - also re-run qmake on your *.pro file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you declare script in your pro ?

```
 QT += script
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to add to your `*.pro` file line `QT += script`, `undefined reference` usually means, that linker cannot find the library.